# How do I find the number of subsets of a specific cardinality

Tags: combinatorics

Given a set S with cardinality N, does a formula exist to calculate the number of subsets  with cardinality M?

For instance, if N=5, and M=3; how many subsets are there within S with cardinality M?

Here is some extra info for each cardinality...maybe it helps.

```
Cardinality 0 = 1 subset
Cardinality 1 = 5 subsets
Cardinality 2 = 10 subsets
Cardinality 3 = 10 subsets
Cardinality 4 = 5 subsets
Cardinality 5 = 1 subset
```

So, set S contains 32 subsets total, but I just want to find the number of subsets for M.

Thanks for your insight...I thought this would be easy, but can't crack it.

Comment: That's the definition of the [binomial coefficfient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) $\binom NM$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient): the number of $k$-element subsets of a set of size $n$ is $$n!\over k!(n-k)!,$$ or "$n\choose k$" (pronounced "$n$ choose $k$"). Here "$!$" is the [factorial function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial).$^1$ You can derive this as follows:

- First, we count the *sequences* of $k$ distinct elements of our $n$-element set. The number of these is $n\cdot (n-1)\cdot ...\cdot (n-(k-1))$ - this is an ugly expression, but it's more snappily written as $$n!\over (n-k)!$$ (do you see why?).
- Now we need to "unorder" everything: the above is a terrible upper bound. Every set of $k$ elements can be listed in $k!$ many ways. So the actual number of sets is the number of sequences divided by the "overcounting" - that is, $${({n!\over (n-k)!})\over k!}={n!\over k!(n-k)!}.$$

As to the name, it's a good exercise to convince yourself that $n\choose k$ is the coefficient of the $x^k$ term in the expansion of $(x+1)^n$.

Incidentally, looking at the values of the binomial coefficients leads to a neat combinatorial picture - [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle).

---

$^1$A convention which may seem odd at first, but is definitely the right definition: we set $0!=1$. So when $k=0$ we get $${n!\over k!(n-k)!}={n!\over 1\cdot (n-0)!}={n!\over n!}=1,$$  and similarly when $k=n$. If you think of the factorial function as being defined as "$a!$ is the number of distinct ways to order $a$ objects" *(rather than "multiply all the whole numbers up to $a$")* this makes sense - there's only one way to order no things.

Comment: To the proposer: This is an example of the method of multiple counting.

Comment: The other 2 answers are also good, but this one breaks down exactly what I was asking in the most digestible way.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You effectively have to choose $M$ elements from a list of $N$ where order doesn't matter hence we have
$$\binom{N}{M}=\frac{N!}{M!(N-M)!}$$
possible choices. It is well known also that the set $S$ contains $2^N$ subsets in total.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by the binomial theorem the number of subsets with cardinality $k$ in a set with cardinality $M$ is $\binom{M}{k}$.

Let $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^n$ be the elements in the set $E$. Write any subset of $E$ asa a multiplication of elements from the subset, e.g. if $U=\{x_1,x_3,x_4\}\subset E$ then we will say $U\sim x_1x_3x_4$. Then the polynomial
$$(x_1+1)(x_2+1)(\cdots)(x_n+1)$$
has as its terms all possible subsets of $E$. Note that the total power of a term is the cardinality of its respective subset, e.g. $x_1x_3x_4$ has a total power of $3$ and the cardinality of $U$ is $3$. Finally, we determine the number of such subsets with cardinality $m$ by counting the number of terms in this polynomial with power $m$. Equating $x_i=x$ and applying the binomial theorem, we get
$$(x+1)^M=\sum_{j=0}^M\binom{M}{j}x^j$$
where $M$ is the cardinality of $E$. Thus, there are $\binom{M}{k}$ subsets of $E$ with cardinality $k$.